# How to interpret list as an integer in python

Tags: python

I am fetching data from MySQL database which is then converted to a list in python. 
Since the data being fetched is of integer type, I am passing it as index to find character within a string. 
I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

How can I treat my list as an index and pass it to a string to find a character within a text?

Here is my code

```
import urllib2
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'sample_db');

with con:

    cur1 = con.cursor()
    cur1.execute("SELECT site_id FROM positive_outcomes")

    row1 =  [item[0] for item in cur1.fetchall()]

site_id_list = row1

uniprot_url = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"  # constant Uniprot Namespace

def get_fasta(site):

    with open('Q9L422_112.fasta', 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()
        str1 = data[site:site+20]
        temp = data[site-1:site-1-20:-1]
        str2 = temp[::-1]
        print str2+str1


def main():
    # iterate over the list of IDS
    for k,v in enumerate(site_id_list):
        get_fasta(v)

    # or read from a text file
    # input_file = open("positive_copy.txt").readlines()
    # get_fasta(input_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: please add the code causing the error.

Comment: @akashkarothiya, please check now

Comment: which line generates the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess the exception is here

```
row1 =  [item[0] for item in cur1.fetchall()]
```

What you want is probably

```
row1 =  [(item[0] for item in cur1.fetchall())[0]]
```

Still, it's not very efficient. Use `cursor.fetchone()` instead

```
row1 =  [cur1.fetchone()[0]]
```

It's still not safe, though, since `curl.fetchone()` may returns `None` if no results found.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t handle a list like an int.

Guessing you can recover one value of the list (and parse it if it is needed) or use a dictionary for assigning int to a list:

```
var dict = {1: your_list}
```

or:

```
int i = (int)your_list[i]
```